# Xml Configuration File Reader in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I wanted to read a xml configuration file in java and I found  a library - [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/). This does the task to me. But I was wondering why does some implementations tries to use either JAXB or Stax to parse the xml and reinvent the wheel which the above library does the task to you easily.

I wanted to know the pros of using JAXB or Stax against the library to read a xml configuration file.

Comment: read on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057977/which-xml-parser-to-use-here

Comment: this is a performance comparison http://dublintech.blogspot.com/2011/12/jaxb-sax-dom-performance.html

Comment: These comparisons are good if we are streaming xml and if we want to parse them online. But when we read configuration file in which we can neglect the performance or memory constraint because it is just a start up cost. So i was wondering why we need to write a parser for startup configuration if there is a library that we can use to ease the workload ? Correct me if i m wrong at this argument

Comment: That common-configuration library looks very good, but if you have issues with it and just want to do XML consider my little library with similar syntax for accessing the xml:  https://github.com/MorganConrad/xen